# Outlook Oauth - send emails with wl.imap scope in php

Tags: windows, oauth, outlook, live, hotmail

I would like to automate sending few emails using Live Connect API.

I had been looking at this page here from the Live Connect SDK and i found is this : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh243646.aspx : it is stating exactly :

> **wl.imap** The wl.imap scope enables read and write access to a user's
>   email using IMAP, and send access using SMTP

I wanted to use that scope to use the smtp send email right, Im able to get the access token however there is no doc about how to communicate with smtp server etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this example that is for gmail:

http://www.chargenevier.com/2013/02/google-smtp-and-oauth2-authentication/

For outlook you need change this:

```
$config = array('ssl' => 'tls', 'port' => '587', 'auth' => 'oauth2', 'xoauth2_request' => $initClientRequestEncoded);
$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp-mail.outlook.com', $config);
```